# Relacion de tablas MySQL

Tags: mysql, tablas, relaciones

Tengo 2 tablas independientes que quiero normalizar

```
Trabajador: id, nombre, dni, sueldo, tipo_planilla
Freelancer, id, nombre, dni, sueldo, tipo_proyecto
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que los datos `nombre - dni - sueldo`, esten en una tabla aparte porque son datos que se repiten en las 2 tablas.

Lo que pense fue crear una tercera tabla donde esten esos datos y agregar un campo `union_id` y `tipo` para distinguir ambas tablas, asi:

```
Trabajador: id, tipo_planilla
Freelancer: id, tipo_proyecto

TraFreData: id, nombre, dni, sueldo, union_id, tipo (1: Trabajador - 2: Freelancer)
```

Como ven, la tabla `TraFreData` tiene los datos de las 2 tablas anteriores y solo para unir con las 2 utilizo el `union_id` y `tipo`, aqui un ejemplo:

```
Trabajador: 1 | "PlanillaX"
Freelancer: 1 | "ProyectoX"
TraFreData: 1 | "Juan" | "75412545" | "2500" | 1 | 1
TraFreData: 1 | "Maria" | "75685415" | "1500" | 1 | 2
```

Las tablas `Trabajador - Freelancer` no se pueden unir porque le agregara mas campos que van a ser exclusivamente de esas tablas.

Si no me entendieron, quiero crear una tabla adicional para colocar los datos que se comparten de las tablas `Trabajador - Freelancer`

Gracias a todos!

Comment: Creo que se te armo lio con el nombre de las tablas. Considera [edit] tu pregunta para acomodarlo. ¿Es necesario que existan `Tabla01` y `Tabla03` o acaso pueden unificarse?

Comment: @Marcos ok lo pondre con nombres para que se entienda mejor, y si cada una trabaja de forma independiente pero comparten los mismos datos que la tabla03

Comment: Tienes que pensar que realacion tienen. Un medico trabaja en uno o varios hospitales y un hospital puede tener a 1 o varios medicos por tanto relacio N:M necesitas una tabla hospital una medico y una tabla intermedia que tenga las claves primaria de ambos, Por poner un ejemplo

Comment: @Marcos Listo! Espero que se entienda mejor

Comment: @bemoba1437 Creo que tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Por lo que entiendo buscas saber si lo que estas haciendo esta "bien" y al respuesta va a depender de que opinen los demás. Funcionar, funciona, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui hay mucho que comentar...

Tu idea tal y como la quieres desarrollar no es correcta...

porque rompe con las reglas basicas de las base de datos relacionales, con la recursividad, y con la integridad de los datos.....

tu tienes dos tablas  que tienen dos campos cada una

por ejemplo

**tabla1--> campo1 y campo2
tabla2--> campo3 y campo4**

si quieres unir estos dos tablas en una tercera no puedes hacerlo asi

**tabla3--> campo1, campo2 , campo3, campo4**

porque estarias repitiendo informacion en tabla3 y en tabla1 /tabla2

y eso provocaria repeticion de la informacion y que no se actualizen correctamente los datos en algun momento ( integridad de los datos )

en su defecto deberias crear un id( o clave primaria) para tabla1 y tabla2 y luego unir esos id en tabla3

por ejemplo

**tabla1--> idtabla1,campo1 y campo2**

**tabla2--> idtabla2,campo3 y campo4**

**tabla3--> idtabla1, idtabla2**

Pero respecto a tu ejemplo ,yo no lo haria uniendo dos tablas en una intermedia ¿porque? porque "trabajador"  jerarquicamente es superior a freelancer, es decir una empresa puede tener trabajadores freelancer y no freelancers....., lo optimo seria colocar en un campo  dentro de la tabla trabajador que se llame freelancer, y que se guarde como true o false, peo si aun asi quieres crear dos tablas diferentes, la estructura mas logico para tu caso seria esta

**Tabla trabajador -->campos: id trabajador , nombre trabajador, ......**

**Tabla freelancer --> campos : id freelancer , idtrabajador, (y otros campos que no sean del trabajador)**

de esta forma unirias el trabajador con freelancer mediante la clave primaria del trabajador